# hostapd clients don't get ipv4 addresses

Tags: wifi, hostapd, ipv4, access-point

I'm trying to setup a raspberrypi 4 as a wifi access point. Following the [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point.md) I managed to bridge my eth0 interface and setup hostapd. The bridges IP is provided by an exisiting DHCP server on the network in contrast to the documentation.
The problem I'm facing is that none of the connected wifi devices are getting an IPv4 address. They are capable of connecting to the internet by IPv6 though but then fail to connect to any IPv4 target on the internet.
Browsing IPv6 based websites works fine from any wifi client (Android or Windows 10).

> Linux raspberrypi4 4.19.75-v7l+ #1270 SMP Tue Sep 24 18:51:41 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
>   hostapd v2.8-devel

Comment: if the module [br_netfilter](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) is currently loaded, then iptables might filter bridged traffic. So do you have this module loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A.B's comment is actually right. My raspi and the current raspbian on it do load the br_netfilter module. Upon removing it and after restarting hostapd all my clients do now get valid IPv4 adresses. Inserting the module breaks the functionality again.
Thank you A.B!

Comment: actually you can change your rules so they work when the module is loaded (because it's usually loaded to have the `-m phydev` match module work). Details there: [7. Two possible ways for frames/packets to pass through the iptables PREROUTING, FORWARD and POSTROUTING chains](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7)